# Server config or how to run nodejs in remote server

Tags: angular, server, angular-universal

I guess this is a simple question. But for some reason after some research I dont make it work. I know I am missing something simple. But since 2 weeks I cannot make my project in production.

- I have a angular5 + universal that should run in a nodejs server.
- My server provider X says that the nodejs is available in the server. The call takes place under:

  **/usr/bin/node**
- Do I have to create this route?
- Is it already there but in other upper directory of what I have access?

Thanks in advance and sorry for such a simple question.

Gr

Comment: It will depend on your hosting service. First of all, did you manage to run your universal app locally?

Comment: Yes I was able to run it in localhost. After I did the build and dist folder was generated. I call it with the command node dist/server which listen in localhost:4000. And everything runs as I expected.Then my question is: 
without console access from server. Is there a way to start the node app? In this case how? 
for running node dist/server

Comment: Ok, finally managed to start the project as a service and address it with the htaccess. The task left is to make it forever active with pm2.